# Selecionando o 'src' de um input usando ID no JQuery

Tags: jquery, if, atributos

```
if(!$("#src-img[src='']")){

}else{

};
```

Gostaría de saber o que há de errado nessa seleção no if, no caso, quero que, se um valor esteja setado no atributo src, ele execute o if, caso contrário, o else.

*Por isso coloquei o ' ! '

Comment: Podes explicar o que queres fazer? assim como está fica confuso pois `$(...)` retirna um objeto e dá sempre `true` quando convertido para boleano; e como IDs são únicas esse seletor `#src-img[src='']` não faz muito sentido... será que queres usar `if (!$('#src-img').attr('src')){`?

Comment: como eu faria para pegar o valor do src e comparar se é vazio ou se possui algo ?

Comment: Nesse caso é [como sugeri no comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173062/selecionando-o-src-de-um-input-usando-id-no-jquery/173083#comment356707_173062) acima.

Comment: mas ai ele não compara só se a propriedade existe ou não? pois posso definir ela, mas deixá-la vazia, e mesmo assim ele retornaria como se tivesse algo digitado nela, não ?

Comment: Com `.attr()` ele vai buscar o valor. Se o valor for uma string vazia ele dá `false`.

Comment: ah sim, coloca a resposta ai, se der certo aqui já tem a resposta garantida :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se percebi bem, o que procuras é saber se um dado elemento com o id `#src-img` tem ou não um atributo `src` atribuído. Para isso podes usar seletores diferentes.

Exemplo para clarificar:

```js
['#src-imgA', '#src-imgB', '#src-imgC'].forEach(function(id) {
    console.log(id);
    console.log(!!$(id).attr('src'));
    console.log(!!$(id + "[src]").length);
    console.log('-------');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="src-imgA" />
<img id="src-imgB" src="" />
<img id="src-imgC" src="/o/meu/url" />
```

O resultado comentado:

```
#src-imgA
false     // o elemento existe, mas o atributo "src" está vazio/não existe
false     // o elemento existe mas como não tem atributo "src" o seletor falha
-------
#src-imgB
false     // o elemento existe mas o atributo "src" está vazio
true      // o elemento existe e tem um atributo "src" (ele não verifica se está vazio)
-------
#src-imgC
true
true
-------
```

Answer (score 5):

Você poderia usar o .attr assim:

```
if($('#img').attr('src') != ""){

}
```

Dessa forma ele vai verificar se o atributo src do seu elemento imagem não está vazio e se não estiver o if será true, caso contrário pode colocar um else.

Comment: Eu acho essa solução mais elegante do que a minha.

Comment: É possível fazer somente com `if( $('#img').attr('src') )` também @LeoLetto. Quando não se passa nenhuma verificação específica, ele testa se é uma string vazia, 0, undefined, null, espaços.

Answer (score 3):

Quando o jQuery não encontra nenhum elemento, vem um objeto `arraylike` vazio. Isso não é considerado logicamente falso pelo javascript, então o código que você postou é equivalente a:

```
if (true) {
}
```

O que você pode fazer, é dar uma olhada na propriedade `length` do retorno do jQuery. Se você não obteve nenhum elemento, o `length` vai ser zero. Aí você pode comparar...

```
if ($("blablabla").length !== 0) {
}
```

Ou usar o length direto, já que zero é considerado logicamente falso.

```
if ($("blablabla").length) {
}
```